# Aでもお世話になる meaning question

Tags: grammar, kansai-ben

This is a rather quick question. I have the following line:

> ココの方々にはこの子の事でもお世話になってますし
>
> 気にせんといてください

Context: Person A has been coming to group B every day and assisting them and they were helping her with her problem too. She sneezes, group B is worried it might be because they were making her come help them, A waves them off.

So if the above sentence was just:

> ココの方々にはお世話になってますし気にせんといてください

I'd have it as:

> I am so grateful to everyone here for your help, so please don't worry/mind me.

But I have the この子の事でも right before it, and I'm not sure what part it acts in this with particle でも at the end. I can see two options:

Option 1: she is thanking them for help, even for help taking care of her kid

> I am so grateful to all of you here, even for helping me with this kid, so please don't mind us/me

Option 2: she is grateful to them, but is also saying even the girl is grateful

> I and even this girl are so grateful to all of you here for everything you have done for us, so please don't worry about me/us

So which one is it, or did I make a mistake. Oh and yeah せんといて is Osaka-ben shenanigans and stands for しないで in standard.

As a side note, why would someone use katakana for ここ, like A did here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The でも is not "even". It's 「～のこと**で**お世話になる」(で = case particle) + 「も」(also).

Comment: Sooo, option 1 with too?

Comment: @4thDimension はい、そうですね。I am so grateful / I owe a lot to all of you here, also for helping me with this kid (as well as for helping me with other things), so please don't worry about me. って感じです。

Answer (score 0):

The use of でも in this context is to humble oneself (self-deprecatory), or in this case one's child. It can be considered a filler word, like ちょっと, not necessary for translation to English.

The use of katakana for ここ is just a way of italicizing the word. When using ここ or これ to represent a group (as a substitution for the group's proper name) the katakana version might be used. Kana can be flexible that way.

So, I believe that 'Option 1', without the 'even' would be closest.